# tailwind not working after trying every solution online

Tags: tailwind-css

I have done absolutely everything from the documation, and I have searched and tried everything three times while trying to fix this beautiful tailwind but still, no success. Some classes just won't work. I a have the config file and the html, css files in the same folder.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}




<link rel="stylesheet" href="./tailwind/output.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

<div class="flex w-screen h-auto justify-center">
  <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-[20px]"> <-- not working
    <div class="w-[200px] border-2 border-white">Div1</div>  <-- not working
    <div class="w-[200px] border-2 border-white">Div2</div> <-- not working
    <div class="w-[200px] border-2 border-white">Div3</div> <-- not working
  </div>
</div>
```

styles.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

@apply won't work

also ran

```
npx tailwindcss -i styles.css  -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do the styles not apply? Is it just a single style that's not applying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet is not in the right folder:

```js
npx tailwindcss -i styles.css  -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

```html
                                 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./tailwind/output.css" />
```

Comment: @apply still won't work in the styles.css file, but other than that it fixed the classes, thanks. I had two output.css files, one in the dist and on in the tailwind folder, and it was watching the dist folder one instead of the tailwind one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./tailwind/output.css" />`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/output.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to fix the issue

**change**

```
<link href="./dist/output.css">
```

**to**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/output.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure content attr in tailwind.config.js properly. for me, I set up something like that
   content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
2. this solution solve my problem when i developing a vite-react project. It's actually official guidance comes from tailwind.
   you can try to install tailwind by postcss
   https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss